# Помещение объектов в список в нужной очередности

Tags: java, алгоритм

Приветствую. Есть задание:

> Создать программу обработки текста учебника по программированию с использованием классов: Символ, Слово, Предложение, Знак препинания и др.

Интересует такая штука. Получаю я текст с файлика, разбиваю его соответственно в классы Символ, Слово, Предложение, Знак препинания. Как потом эти объекты засунуть в лист, но чтобы они соответствовали порядку, который был с исходного файлика. На ум пришла идея создавать лист, где будет условный идентификатор для каждого класса, как w,s,c,se и т.д., и соответственно к этому писать в новый файл. Поделитесь соображениями.

Answer (score 2):

Мои идеи таковы, что у вас есть класс *Предложение*, в этот класс входит лист *слово*, в *слово* входит лист *символ* и лист *знак препинания*. Т.е. по логике все как в жизни: это в этом, а то в том, а именно в данном случае - символ в слове, со словом знак препинания (после слова), а слово в предложении. И будет у вас упорядоченный список слов в предложении, которые по очереди можно выводить на экран или в файл допустим, методом 'print()'. Далее, если книга довольно большая, то лучше разбивать ее на абзацы и листинги, и по очереди все исполнять. Т.е. ввести класс *Абзац* (`Paragraph`) и класс *Листинг*. Или, если задание не особо важно сделать сложным, то просто класс *Абзац*. И в этом классе будет лист *предложение*. Вот и будет у вас порядок.
Еще идея реализации:
     Есть класс *читатель*, и класс *обработчик*, головная функция (чаще всего *main(String[] args)*) создает класс *читатель*, который имеет примерно следующее:

```
public class Reader {
    public boolean hasNext(){
        /*
        Этот метод возвращает true, если 
         в книге есть еще один абзац
         */
    }
    public Paragraph getNextParagraph() {
        /*
          Этот метод считывает следующий параграф,
          заносит в класс абзац нужные данные,
           и возвращает его.
         */
    }
}
```

В классе *обработчик* находится все, что надо сделать с абзацем (там вывести его, отформатировать, в общем что угодно). А в головном методе сделать что-то вроде

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Reader reader = new Reader("Путь_к_книге_которую_открыть");
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        //Создаем класс обработчика, в котором параметр конструктора 
        // объект класса Paragraph
        Worker worker = new Worker(reader.getNextParagraph());
        //Делаем все, что надо
        worker.work();
    }
}
```

Ну и все.

Comment: Не понял на счет листингов. Как я буду знать какой объект листинга выводить если будет предложение "Hi Bill Gates, i'm Steave Jobs." или типо того. Я разобью на слова, символы, для каждого елемента будет создан собственный обьекты соответствующих классов, как же их правильно распихать в лист ?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, привожу более подробный ответ.
     Для начала класс Worker:

```
public class Worker {
    private Paragraph paragraph;

    //Конструктор
    public Worker(Paragraph p) {
        this.paragraph = p;
    }

    /*
      Далее методы по работе с текстом или что-то там еще
        надо сделать...
     */
}
```

Как помним, параграф создает класс `Reader`.
Далее, вам интересно, что будет в классе `Paragraph`. Он должен принимать один параграф из исходного файла. Логику реализации придумать - дело техники (т.е. ваше). Т.е. по сути, он должен принимать, например, строковый тип, разбивать его на предложения, так же как и класс *предложение* (Sentence) должен принимать строковый тип и разбивать принятое предложение на слова и знаки препинания, и отправлять их своему подклассу - *слову*. Т.е. логика заключается в том, что *каждый* класс должен делать *свое*. Это и есть основы **ООП**. Вот класс Paragraph:

```
public class Paragraph {
    //Объявляем лист предложений
    private List<Sentence> sentenses;
    //Объявляем конструктор
    public Paragraph(String text) {
        sentenses = new ArrayList<Sentence>();
        List<String> tSentenses = new ArrayList<String>();
        /*
         Тут надо разбить пришедший текст на предложения, после чего получится 
          лист строк, которые и будут предложениями.
         */
        //Идем дальше:
        //Тут мы заполняем наш список предложений в классе
        for (String s : tSentenses) 
            sentenses.add(new Sentence(s));
    }

    /*Ну и, т.к. мы будем использовать в качестве основного источника получения
      всяких там данных из текста, то реализовать тут можно геттеры и сеттеры 
       отдельных частей параграфа.

      А т.к. все предложения заносятся последовательно, то
      и порядок, конечно же, сохранится.
     */

    public String getParagraphText() {
        //Будет совмещать назат весь параграф. Например так:
        String res = "";
        // Извлекаем содержимое предложений из нашего класса.
        for (Sentence sent : sentenses) {
            res += sent.getSentenseText();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

По абсолютной аналогии, сделать и класс *предложение* `Sentence`. Уже ясно, что он должен содержать конструктор, принимающий строковый тип, и должен содержать хотя бы метод, возвращающий предложение, хранящееся в нем.

И обратите внимание, что там класс в классе, а в том классе еще один класс. Т.е. еще раз подчеркну: **Все как в реале - предложение в параграфе, слова в предложении. И тут: класс *предложение* в классе *параграф*, а в классе *предложение* класс *слово* и т.д.**

Answer (score 2):

*В дополнение к предыдущим ответам:*

Логичнее будет сделать **`Предложение`** списком объектов типа **`Лексема`**, а уже от класса **`Лексема`** унаследовать **`Слово`** и **`Знак препинания`**.

Тогда знаки препинания не будут привязаны к словам, что правильно — ведь они таковыми не являются. Также будет легче вести статистику знаков и слов: не нужно будет проверять содержимое и делить его при каждом проходе.

Comment: Истинно верно!

Answer (score 0):

у вас прямо в условии задачи все написано. итак по порядку:

1) общий интерфейс

```
public class Parsable
{
    private String value = null;

    public Parsable(String value)
    {
        setValue(value);
    }    
    public List<Parsable> parse()
    {
        return new LinkedList();
    }
    // методы getValue(), setValue
}
```

думаю интуитивно понятно что все комплексные обьекты будут парсится (на выходе LinkedList - т.к. он сохраняет порядок), и по умолчанию мы будем возвращать пустой список (подходит для символов и знаков препинания)

2) самый "главный" класс - вершина дерева

```
class Text extends Parsable {...}
```

который хранит строку - сам текст, а результатом вызова метода parse является список обектов - предложений и символов разделителей (знаки препинания (точки), знаки пробела, знаки табуляции, перевода строки, итд...).

3) обьект 2го уровня - предложение

```
class Sentence extends Parsable {...}
```

результат вызовом метода parse является список слов и знаков разделителей (допустимых внутри предложения, - запятые, двоеточия, пробелы, итд...)

4) обьект 3го уровня

```
class Word extends Parsable {...}
```

результатом parse для этого класса будет список символов

5) для разбора и обхода дерева будет использоватся шаблон Visitor: вы создаете базовый обьект Text и вызываете для него метод parse, который возвращает список обьектов из которых он состоит. и для каждого из них вызывается метод parse. более детальную информацию ищите сами (гугл: шаблон проэктирования Visitor)

Comment: скорее за все для вас это непринципиально, но так как у вас будет много повторяющихся элементов можно добавить Factory класс который будет хранить "ссылки" на готовые обьекты. напр:
Map<String, Parsable> cache = new HasMap<String, Parsable>();
cache.put("a", new Parsable("a"));  
а еще можно усложнить код добавив статичиский инициализатор/конструктор и забить по умолчанию туда все допустимые буквы, знаки препинания итд.